The website is called before pressing enter ASP.NET Core MVC
I created new project with ASP.NET Core MVC latest version. It shows a strange behavior.
My code:
public class VerificationController(TimeProvider timeProvider) : Controller
{
    [Route("email-verification")]
    public IActionResult EmailVerification()
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentYear = timeProvider.GetUtcNow().Year;
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
        return View();
    }
}

program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<TimeProvider, ZonedTimeProvider>();

builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<IdentityPortalDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Sql")));

var app = builder.Build();

if (builder.Configuration.ShouldMigrateDatabases())
{
    await app.MigrateDatabase();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

await app.RunAsync();

When I launch the project and navigate to https://localhost:7266/ and add / manually after the url, the browser suggests the previous url visited. I pressed the scroll key on the keyboard to the url https://localhost:7266/email-verification without pressing the enter key. Debug will touch the code with the router above (but browser will not do anything and will not change. just hit breakpoint in my code).
Is this behavior correct? Is there any documentation about this? It would be a waste if users misuse this and affect the performance of the website.
Then pressed enter and it will be call again:



I have a quick test just now, and can't reproduce the issue. Could you share more details about your browser(which one and the version), and vs2022 version and so on, thanks~

@Jason Pan Hi I answered in comment below. Thank for your concern

Hi Thanh, I also download the latest Chrome, not facing the issue. Anyway, it's not related to VS2022 and asp.net core.

It seems to be happening on chrome. Does not take place on edge. Stop app and reopen again. Then paste the url on anonymous tab in Chrome and it will be hit the breakpoint !
BTW it seems like this is happening because of the browser not aspnet core
